# Load js files in a specific included php file

Tags: javascript, php

I found some problems to load js files in php file. I have file php **admin-pp-sipp-litbang.php**. Inside that file, I include some php files with **switch case** like that:

```
 <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 main">
        <?php
        switch (@$_GET['modul']) {
            case "beranda":
                include "tampilan-admin-pp/beranda.php";
                break;
            case "permintaanakun":
                include "tampilan-admin-pp/permintaanakun.php";
                break;
            case "permintaanpp":
                include "tampilan-admin-pp/permintaanpp.php";
                break;
            case "chat":
                include "tampilan-admin-pp/chat.php";
                break;
            case "detailsproposal":
                include "tampilan-admin-pp/details_proposal.php";
                break;
            case "detailspermintaanakun":
                include "tampilan-admin-pp/details_permintaanakun.php";
                break;
            case "detailspengguna":
                include "tampilan-admin-pp/details_pengguna.php";
                break;
            default:
                include "tampilan-admin-pp/beranda.php";
        }
        ?>
    </div><!--/.main-->
```

After that, I load js files for tampilan-admin-pp/chat.php on admin-pp-sipp-litbang.php near close body tag . Here are the js files.

```
        <script id="message-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <li class="clearfix">
        <div class="message-data align-right">
            <span class="message-data-time" >{{time}}, Today</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <span class="message-data-name" >Olia</span> <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="message other-message float-right">
            {{messageOutput}}
        </div>
    </li>
</script>

<script id="message-response-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <li>
        <div class="message-data">
            <span class="message-data-name"><i class="fa fa-circle online"></i> Vincent</span>
            <span class="message-data-time">{{time}}, Today</span>
        </div>
        <div class="message my-message">
            {{response}}
        </div>
    </li>
</script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.0/handlebars.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.1.1/list.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="tampilan-admin-pp/chat/jss/load_list_user_chat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tampilan-admin-pp/chat/jss/UserOnline.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="tampilan-admin-pp/chat/jss/index.js"></script>
```

The problem is the js files for tampilan-admin-pp/chat.php affects another included files. How can I load that js files only for tampilan-admin-pp/chat.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you can't just move the `<script>` tags at the bottom of admin-pp-sipp-litbang.php into tampilan-admin-pp/chat.php?

If you need them to be included at the end of admin-pp-sipp-litbang.php, then you will need to use another switch statement or similar logic after the handlebars templates.

UPDATE:

The problem is that your php files are being conditionally included by the `switch` statement but your "chat" javascript files are being included every time regardless. You need to conditionally include the javascript files as well. You could just add the `<script>` tags to the original `switch` statement, but often javascript is better loaded just before the `</body>` ending tag, as you have done. To keep that characteristic, add another `switch` statement at the bottom of admin-pp-sipp-litbang.php before including the js files.

**So**

```
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.0/handlebars.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.1.1/list.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="tampilan-admin-pp/chat/jss/load_list_user_chat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tampilan-admin-pp/chat/jss/UserOnline.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="tampilan-admin-pp/chat/jss/index.js"></script>
```

**Becomes:**

```
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.0/handlebars.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.1.1/list.min.js'></script>

<?php switch($_GET['modul']):
    case 'chat': ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tampilan-admin-pp/chat/jss/load_list_user_chat.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tampilan-admin-pp/chat/jss/UserOnline.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tampilan-admin-pp/chat/jss/index.js"></script>
    <?php break;?>
<?php endswitch;?>
```

That way you can add other `case` statements that match the other `include`s at the top of the file to conditionally include their javascript too.

Comment: I have tried to move them into tampilan-admin-pp/chat.php, but get some errors when I checked from browser. It get 404 file js not found.

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain the second suggestion.

Comment: Great I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to make some variable inside tampilan-admin-pp/chat.php.
Something like `$chatIncluded = true;`

Then conditional rendering of script tag, if chatIncluded is defined and is true, load JS file.

Comment: Sorry I just can't get it. Could you please give an example?

Comment: I have never been working with handlebars before, but the way i am thinking is this:
1. Create variable inside tampilan-admin-pp/chat.php - `$chatIsIncluded = true`.
2. Then if that variable is defined, you can pass it to handlebars.
3.Then i guess, handlebars can use that variable to conditionally render that script tag that is making problem. If variable is true, render script tag. :)

Comment: My comment was wrong :/ Try like this
1. Create variable inside tampilan-admin-pp/chat.php - `$chatIsIncluded = true`.
2. Use php code again where you do scripts loading and load that file only `if (isset($chatIsIncluded )) {//Put loading script tag here}`